# RequireHttps vs deriving from RequireHttpsAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, https, attributes

I'm trying to implement HTTPS on selected pages of my site. Using the attribute **RequireHttps** works but causes problems testing as we don't have a cert installed locally.

The solution I'm looking for will need to ignore localhost and ignore one test server while working on our second test server where we do have a cert in place.

Some further background on this. The aim is to move the site gradually to https. It's an ecommerce site so obviously portions are already secure and I know that for many reasons moving the entire site to secure is a good thing. I also know that once you move from Page A to Page B where B is secure then it won't go back to HTTP when you move back to A, that's fine.
I want to move the site in stages just in case there are problems with things like mismatched content, site maps, SEO, google ranking etc.

Some of the various solutions I have tried  - I've implemented a class derived from the RequireHttps attribute as follows:

```
 public class CustomRequireHttps : RequireHttpsAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleNonHttpsRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url != null && (!String.Equals(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                                              && !String.Equals(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "HEAD", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                                              && !filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host.Contains("localhost")
                                                              && !filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host.Contains("testing")))
        {
            base.HandleNonHttpsRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

And have applied this attribute to one page but it hasn't worked as intended, it either applies HTTPS to all pages on the site or doesn't work at all.

I have also tried this solution which works but only on localhost and not on the two test servers:

```
#if !DEBUG
[RequireHttps] 
#endif
```

Then I tried overriding the OnAuthorizartion method like so:

```
 public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }

        if (filterContext.HttpContext != null && filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsLocal)
        {
            return;
        }

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
```

It worked locally but once I got it onto the server with the test cert suddenly every page is HTTPS which I do not understand as I've only used this derived attribute on one page.

So, what I'm looking to achieve is to implement HTTPS on a select number of pages on my site. This HTTPS request needs to be ignored on localhost and the first test server but, it needs to **NOT** to be ignored on the second test server which has a cert.

So far it either doesn't work at all or is on every page on the site.

However, and this is the kicker, If I use the RequireHttps attribute it works perfectly on the second test server but causes problems on all servers without a cert. By 'works perfectly' I mean it implements HTTPS only on the pages where I've used that attribute and does not suddenly switch all pages to secure.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

There can be a lot going on, for example when your links are local, when a switch is made to HTTPS, all pages are HTTPS (not applying require HTTPS doesn't switch back to HTTP). From a security standpoint, you should serve all pages from HTTPS when you need it for a subset of pages (otherwise, you might share secure cookies / login tokens over unencrypted HTTP). So probably your attribute is applied, and all subsequent requests are served over SSL.

Secondly, testing on localhost request uri will serve the page over HTTP on your second server. My opinion to solve this problem is to create a switch in your web.config if the pages should be served over HTTPS. Check this switch in your global filterConfig:

```
public static class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        var useSsl = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["useSsl"]);
        if (useSsl )
        {
            filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is kind of how our current system works and it is OK except it doesn't allow for the selective implementation of HTTPS. I realise that once you're on a secure connection it doesn't switch back and that fine. The aim here is to eventually move the entire site to HTTPS but to do so over stages. So at the moment when you go to the checkout it's secure obviously, but I want to also add one or two other pages that are secure. If there are no problems with them then move one or two more....and so on.